# overwrite value in file

Tags: c, string, file

I use linux and compile in gcc

I have The next program :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define F ".test.txt"
int main(){
 FILE *fl;
 char s[20],d[]="dog";
 char *token;

 fl=fopen(F,"a");
 fprintf(fl,"cat;12;\ndog;78;\nbird;56;\n");
 fclose(fl);
 fl=fopen(F,"a+");

 while(fgets(s,20,fl)){
  token=strtok(s,";");
  if(strcmp(d,token)==0)
   //here I want to overwrite the number after dog word
  token=NULL;
 }
fclose(fl);
}
```

I want if possible overwrite the after dog's word number to another given by user but I don't know how to do that someone know how to overwrite this number without overwrite all file?

Comment: first make the change in the memory buffer, next seek to the position in the file where the buffer starts. write the change. Note that it will not be possible to change the number of digits, ie it is not possible to change 78 into 123.

Comment: `fseek(fl,-2,SEEK_CUR);  fputc(digit1, fl); fputc(digit2,fl);` shoud do it. digit1 and digit2 must be character digits and not integers.

Comment: As the "dog's word number" and the  number "given by user" may differ in textual length: Example "78" shorter than "123". Code needs to potentially re-write the entire file.

Comment: @chux ... or at least the tail end of the file. But honestly, with a file that size, rewriting the whole thing anyway is just far simpler than all the parsing and figuring out what bits to rewrite...